# How to handle generic enums (Binary operator '<' cannot be applied)

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I would like to implement a generic struct to handle many properties. Each of these properties (qualities, flaws...) are arrays of enum, both conforming to the Options protocol.
As I declare OptionType conforming to the Options protocol, and thus to RawRepresentable, I have difficulties to understand the error, and more generally, how to manage generic enum types.
Any guidance would be welcome !

Many thanks,
Jo

```
struct Property<OptionType: Options> {
    
    var options: [OptionType]
    var label: String {
        "\(OptionType.Type.self)"
    }
    var allSortedOptions: [OptionType] {
        let allOptions = OptionType.allCases as! [OptionType]
        return allOptions.sorted(by: {$0.rawValue < $1.rawValue})
        //Won't compile: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'OptionType.RawValue' operands
    }
}

protocol Options: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable {}
extension Options {}

enum OptionQualities: String, Options {
    case polite, handsome, smart, funny, enjoyable, articulated
}
enum OptionFlaws: String, Options {
    case lazy, chatty, oftenLate, dirty, agressive, complaining
}
```

Comment: What is the expected order after sorting it? Lexicographic order?

Comment: I think alphabetical order. It's what I get when I don't use generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a constrain to your protocol Options RawRepresentable RawValue to String:

```
protocol Options: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable where RawValue == String { }
```

or If you may have other enumeration types you can simply constrain RawValue to Comparable protocol as suggested by Martin R

```
protocol Options: CaseIterable, RawRepresentable where RawValue: Comparable { }
```

Note that there is no need to cast allCases `as! [OptionType]`

```
var allSortedOptions: [OptionType] {
    OptionType.allCases.sorted(by: { $0.rawValue < $1.rawValue })
}
```

Comment: Or `where RawValue: Comparable`

Comment: Yes!! That's what I was missing   ! Thanks Leo

Comment: @Joshua you should also consider declaring it as constant instead of a computed property `let allSortedOptions = OptionType.allCases.sorted { $0.rawValue < $1.rawValue }`

Comment: I'm not quiet sure I understand the choice between let and computed property: is it for memory management ?

Comment: This would avoid sorting the elements every time you call this property

Comment: I get it. So more a performance issue, then. Thanks!